# rearranging a trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

this is a problem that im not 100% can be done as i derived the equation myself but please help if you can and if it cant be done let me know:

i need the end product to be $\tan(\theta) = \ldots$
and for there to be no $\theta$ on the RHS.
equation is:
$$\frac{96.04 \cdot D^2}{\left(U \cdot \cos(\theta)\right)^2} = 2\left(U \cdot \sin(\theta)\right)^2 + (19.6 \cdot W)$$

where D, U and W are constants.

thanks so much in advance!!

------edit-------

i believe i owe you both an apology, it turns out i made a mistake earlier on in my equation so the one i posted was not possible. i only came to this conclusion after subbing in the data values i had into both answers and getting imaginary numbers back. so if i could be a pain, here is the updated (and verified) equation:

\begin{equation*}
\frac{D}{U\cos (\theta )}=\frac{U\sin (\theta )}{C}+( \frac{A+U^{2}\sin
^{2}(\theta )}{B}) ^{0.5}
\end{equation*}

once again im after $\tan(\theta)=$ etc with no ($\theta$) on the RHS

sorry for the mess around and thanks for helping :)

Comment: Do you mean this? $$\frac{D}{U\cos(\theta)}  =  \frac{U\sin(\theta)}{C } +  (\frac{A + U^2\sin^2(\theta)}{B})^{0.5}$$

Comment: yes thats the one, sorry i dont know how to use laTex

Comment: In the present form this equation is more difficult to solve than before. For some basic information about LaTeX see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: thanks for the links. unfortunately this is the simplest form i can get it to. is it still possible to do or am i wasting my time?

Comment: This new equation, although solvable in full generality, its solutions are huge. See my answer.

Comment: wow yes that got very big very quickly. thankyou for your assistance, thats certainly not something i would like to have arrived at myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE (answer to the revised question). If we multiply the edited equation by $C\sqrt{B}U\cos \theta \neq 0$, we get
the equivalent equation

\begin{equation*}
\sqrt{B}CD=\sqrt{B}U^{2}\sin \theta \cos \theta +CU\left( A+U^{2}\sin
^{2}\theta \right) ^{1/2}\cos \theta .
\end{equation*}

Using the definition of $\tan \theta =\frac{\sin \theta }{\cos \theta }$ and
the fundamental trigonometric identity $\sin ^{2}\theta +\cos ^{2}\theta =1$
, we are able to express $\sin \theta $ and $\cos \theta $, as well as $\sin
\theta \cos \theta $, in terms of $t=\tan \theta $. A possible derivation is
as follows. From

\begin{equation*}
\tan ^{2}\theta =\frac{\sin ^{2}\theta }{\cos ^{2}\theta }=\frac{\sin
^{2}\theta }{1-\sin ^{2}\theta }=\frac{1-\cos ^{2}\theta }{\cos ^{2}\theta }=
\frac{1}{\cos ^{2}\theta }-1
\end{equation*}

we obtain successively
\begin{eqnarray*}
\cos ^{2}\theta  &=&\frac{1}{1+\tan ^{2}\theta } \\
&\Rightarrow &\cos \theta =\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\tan ^{2}\theta }}=\pm \frac{
1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}} \\
&& \\
\sin ^{2}\theta  &=&\left( 1-\sin ^{2}\theta \right) \tan ^{2}\theta
\Leftrightarrow \sin ^{2}\theta =\frac{\tan ^{2}\theta }{1+\tan ^{2}\theta }=
\frac{t^{2}}{1+t^{2}} \\
&\Rightarrow &\sin \theta =\pm \frac{\tan \theta }{\sqrt{1+\tan ^{2}\theta }}
=\pm \frac{t}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}
\end{eqnarray*}

and

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sin \theta  &=&\cos \theta \tan \theta  \\
&\Leftrightarrow &\sin \theta \cos \theta =\cos ^{2}\theta \tan \theta =
\frac{\tan \theta }{1+\tan ^{2}\theta }=\frac{t}{1+t^{2}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Substituting these expressions in the first equation yields
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{B}CD &=&\frac{\sqrt{B}U^{2}t}{1+t^{2}}+CU\left( A+\frac{U^{2}t^{2}}{
1+t^{2}}\right) ^{1/2}\left( \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^{2}}}\right)  \\
\sqrt{B}CD\left( 1+t^{2}\right) -\sqrt{B}U^{2}t &=&\pm CU\left( A+\left(
A+U^{2}\right) t^{2}\right) ^{1/2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Squaring now both sides and rearranging the terms we obtain the following
quartic equation in $t$

\begin{equation*}
at^{4}+bt^{3}+ct^{2}+dt+e=0
\end{equation*}
whose coefficients are

\begin{eqnarray*}
a &=&BC^{2}D^{2} \\
b &=&-2BCDU^{2} \\
c &=&2BC^{2}D^{2}-C^{2}U^{4}+BU^{4}-AC^{2}U^{2} \\
d &=&-2BCDU^{2} \\
e &=&-2BCDU^{2}-AC^{2}U^{2}+BC^{2}D^{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}

> unfortunately this is the simplest form i can get it to. is it still possible to do or am i wasting my time?

This equation ([after depressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Converting_to_a_depressed_quartic)) although solvable algebraically by an auxiliary cubic equation has huge solutions (see [Wikipedia entry Ferrari's solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Ferrari.27s_solution)).

---

Multiplying your equation by $U^{2}\cos ^{2}\theta\ne 0 $ we get the equivalent
equation

\begin{equation*}
2U^{4}\sin ^{2}\theta \cos ^{2}\theta +19.6WU^{2}\cos ^{2}\theta
-96.04D^{2}=0.
\end{equation*}

Using the identity $\sin ^{2}\theta =1-\cos ^{2}\theta $ and rearranging the
terms we obtain the following quadratic equation in $y=\cos ^{2}\theta $:

\begin{equation*}
ay^{2}+by+c=0\Leftrightarrow y=\frac{1}{2a}\left( -b\pm \sqrt{b^{2}-4ac}
\right) ,
\end{equation*}

whose coefficients are

\begin{equation*}
a=-2U^{4},\quad b=2U^{4}+19.6WU^{2},\quad c=-96.04D^{2}.
\end{equation*}

To get the result we just need to express $\tan \theta $ in terms of $y$

\begin{equation*}
\sin ^{2}\theta +\cos ^{2}\theta =1\Leftrightarrow \tan ^{2}\theta +1=\frac{1
}{\cos ^{2}\theta }=\frac{1}{y}\Leftrightarrow \tan \theta =\pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{y}-1}.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $\displaystyle\tan\theta=u,$

$\displaystyle\cos^2\theta=\frac1{\sec^2\theta}=\frac1{1+\tan^2\theta}=\frac1{1+u^2}$

$\displaystyle\sin^2\theta=\frac{\tan^2\theta}{\sec^2\theta}=\frac{\tan^2\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta}=\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$

or $\displaystyle\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta=1-\frac1{1+u^2}=\frac{u^2}{1+u^2}$

Rearrange the given relation to form a Quadratic Equation in $u=\tan\theta$

Comment: so its definitely possible to reduce this all down to tan(theta)=... ? because im not having a whole lot of luck at the moment

Comment: @jordan6194, in fact as $$\tan^2\theta=$$

Comment: okay thank you ill keep trying, i feel like im making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be ahaha thanks for your help so far

Comment: @jordan6194, please simplify and let me know if you are stuck

Comment: hoping im on track so far, ive gotten it to here but cant eliminate that last tan in the denominator

tan^2(theta).(96.04 . D^2 - (2 . U^4)/(1+tan^2(theta)) = constants.

hopefully thats no too confusing to follow